# CSS selector for last element in case of display:none is not working

Tags: html, css-selectors, less

Need to apply style in the following element:

```
 <div id="box" class="abc">Hello, World!11212</div>
```

It is working when I put `display:none` on the first element, but it is not working when it is on last element

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#box {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* Opera */
  background-color: yellow;
}

.abc:not([style="display:none"]):last-child {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="box" class="abc">Hello, World!</div>
  <div id="box" class="abc">Hello, World!11212</div>
  <div class="abc" style="display:none">Real Time CSS Editor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting here? How do you expect to style something with `display: none`? And if you remove the display your style doesn't target...

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Also IDs need to be unique. Make box a class

Comment: As stated, your HTML is invalid. Delete this question and fix that first. Then come back.

Answer (score 0):

`:last-child` means *last child in its containing element*. It does **not** mean *last in the group of elements matched by the rest of the selector*.

`.abc:not([style="display:none"]):last-child` doesn't match:

- `<div id="box" class="abc">Hello, World!</div>` because it isn't the last child
- `<div id="box" class="abc">Hello, World!11212</div>` because it isn't the last child
- `<div class="abc" style="display:none">Real Time CSS Editor</div>` because it has `style="display:none"`

There is **no** selector that means *last in the group of elements matched by the rest of the selector*.

---

Consider programmatically adding a class to the element you want to target and selecting that instead.

Comment: Too bad there is not a last-of-class selector, then class="abc box" would help